# Is there a SQL API wrapper in Python for swift object storage?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

My OpenStack based project plans to use swift object storage as a database. To ease the development work, I wonder if there is any SQL API wrapper in Python for swift object storage.

If no SQL wrapper, is there any other helper project for swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at python-swift package, while it is not a SQL API wrapper.

[swiftclient documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-swiftclient/swiftclient.html#swiftclient.client.get_account)

[swiftclient api documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/index.html)